# Semi-generic class — "T" does not contain a definition for "Length"

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class, which is doing some serialport communication.
The class should be initialized with type of either `byte[]`, `char[]`, `string`.

The class also provides Queues for storing outgoing data and incoming data

```
class SerialServices<T>
{
  //...
  Queue<T> requestDataQueue;
  Queue<T> responseDataQueue;
  //...
}
```

Problem occures when writing the Data into the SerialPort:

```
public override Task SendData()
{
  //...
  T requestData = requestDataQueue.Dequeue();

  if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
  {
    this.sp.Write(requestData as string);
  }
  else
  {
   this.sp.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
  }
  //...
}
```

`requestData.Length` is not compiling.

Error:

> "T" does not contain a definition for "Length".

I dont even know making the class generic is the right way here, because it isnt really generic...

But Im trying to avoid making three different "overloads" of the class for `string`, `byte[]`, `char[]`.

What is the way to go here?

Comment: Seems like an abuse of generics and what you should actually be doing is using `byte[]` and writing adapters/mappers for other data types.

Comment: If it's not `string`,whats type is it?

Comment: Then it is either `byte[]` or `char[]`

Comment: It is not generic when it can handle only 3 types.  Use method overloads instead.

Comment: What @HansPassant said, especially since one of the three possible types seems to require special handling anyway (`if typeof(T) == typeof(string)`)

Comment: I was thinking of method or ctor overloads as well, but this is maybe not a solution for this problem, since I presume that TS always will want to use the same types for a certain instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant said:

> It is not generic when it can handle only 3 types. Use method overloads instead.

One option (if possible) is to use method overloads as Hans suggested. That is only really feasible if you can directly use the incoming parameters, rather than the need to cache them and process them later on.

You can also make a generic base class, and supply overloads for the specific types you need to support.

Your `SendData` for example, could have different implementations for `byte[]` (`ByteSerialServices : SerialServices<byte[]>`) and `string` (`StringSerialServices : SerialServices<string>`).